# Add timespan to a date?

Tags: coldfusion, timespan, dateadd

Can anyone think of an efficient way of adding a timespan to a date?

Something like the following:

```
    <cfset foo = now() + createTimeSpan(15,12,30,30)>
```

IIRC in a .NET-based CFML engine I could simply use *date.add(timespan)*, but I can't remember the equivalent Java shortcut right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What actually are you asking here?  On one hand you've tagged it as a CF question and use CFML which answers your own question; then you start asking about a Java short cut?

If you want to know how to do it in CFML, then your code sample *is* how you do it in CFML.

If you want to know how to add a CF timespan value (which is just a numeric representation of a number of days) to a Java date, then it seems to be slightly trickier, because the Calendar methods I can find all add the component parts of the timespan, not the whole timespan.

This code demonstrates possibly all the answers you're after (except how to do it in one hit with a Java date/calendar):

```
<cfset dTs = now()><!--- grab now --->
<cfset fTimespan = createTimeSpan(15,12,30,30)><!--- make a timespan --->
<cfset fLater = dTs + fTimespan><!--- add the timespan to now yields a float --->
<cfset sLater = dateFormat(fLater, "yyy-mm-dd") & " " & timeformat(fLater, "HH:MM:SS")><!--- but you can treat a float as a date/time --->
<cfset dLater = createOdbcDateTime(fLater)><!--- or convert it back to a date object --->

<cfset jCal = createObject("java", "java.util.GregorianCalendar").init()><!--- java.util.Date is basically deprecated in favour of calendars --->
<cfset jCal.add(jCal.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15)><!--- one needs to set each part of the timespan separately --->
<cfset jCal.add(jCal.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)>
<cfset jCal.add(jCal.MINUTE, 30)>
<cfset jCal.add(jCal.SECOND, 30)>
<cfset sJCal = jCal.getTime()><!--- this gets a string that CF can use as a date back out of the calendar --->
<cfset bIsDate = isDate(sJCal)><!--- demonstrate that last statement to be true --->
<cfdump var="#variables#"><!--- and all the results --->
```

Does that answer whatever your question actually was?

Comment: You might want to try some meds to help you calm down again.

The example I posted above only returned a float due to the way timespans are stored and I forgot that unlike parseDateTime createOdbcDateTime is able to convert the result again.
So, thanks for your reply, even if the answer came wrapped in some pretty rude manners.

Comment: mz_01, you should have pointed out that you only had a float and wanted a date object as part of your question. Many things can accept a number for a date and handle it ok (e.g. cfqueryparam would be fine with it). I was also thinking "wtf? that's exactly what you do do". I didn't interpret Adam's answer as being rude at all.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that parseDateTime works as expected in [Railo](http://getrailo.org), (where it _does_ convert floats back to date objects). I raised an [issue on the cfbugs tracker](http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=87087) if anyone want to vote for ACF to have this behaviour.

Comment: @Peter, the "expected" behaviour of a CFML tag or function is how it's documented by Adobe to work in CF.  If Railo does it differently, then that's a bug in Railo, not a feature of it.  Don't dress-up the vagaries of Railo where it varies from ColdFusion as "features": at best they're "inconsistencies" (read: "not a GOOD thing").  It's great that you take the time to point out inconsistencies in the various platforms, but make sure to label them as that: inconsistencies.

Comment: The expected behaviour is what _the programmer_ expects. I was referring to the implication that mz_01 expected parseDateTime to work but it didn't. (Whether the expectation is valid is an entirely separate issue.)

If CF's documentation is the authoritative source on what's correct, then _ColdFusion_ has plenty of "inconsistencies" with itself, because it doesn't always do what the docs say it does.

Makes it harder for Railo and OBD when the docs say one thing but the engine does something else - they have to decide which one to follow (and sometimes, when to do things differently entirely).

Comment: Sometimes, differences between Railo and ACF are accidents or bugs, but equally as often they are deliberate and considered changes to make CFML more consistent and rational. It's not vagaries when someone with a lot of experience in both engines has sat down and planned it.

Enhancing parseDateTime to make it work on numeric dates is clearly a good difference. In this case, I don't know whether it was deliberate of incidental due to other changes, but it's certainly a good thing, and something that CF and OBD should implement too.

Comment: ((Ugh. I _really_ wish SO would let us use linebreaks in comments.))